# Array not giving expected answer using split function

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

In this code console.log (name[i]) results in first character of split string(i.e. c ,s,t) but i want name separate like chris. and its giving the expected result on MDN but not on  console on js.

```js
var char=['chris:2255655','sarrah:5456454','taur:5655226'];

var name=new Array();

for(var i=0;i<char.length;++i){
    name=char[i].split(':');
    console.log(name[i]);
}
```

Comment: It’ll be better to tag a language you used as well!

Comment: Why don’t you replace name[i] to name[0]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look like

```js
var char=['chris:2255655','sarrah:5456454','taur:5655226'];

    for(var i=0;i<char.length;++i){   
       var w = char[i].split(":");
       console.log(w[0]);
    }
```

Please check my snippet. It seems that your split was not resulting an array but a string. So you were getting only the first symbol

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```js
var char=['chris:2255655','sarrah:5456454','taur:5655226']

// As array
console.log(char.map(x => x.split(':')[0]))

// As a string
console.log(...char.map(x => x.split(':')[0]))
```

We are using [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to go through each of the strings and [**split**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on `:`.

Since split gives us an array we take the 0 index which contains the name. Since Map returns an array you can either leave as is or [**destructure**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) it with `...` to get its contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
const char=['chris:2255655','sarrah:5456454','taur:5655226'];

const name= [];

for(let i=0;i<char.length;i++){
  let val =char[i].split(':');
  name.push(val[0]);
  console.log(name[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the position of your selection you can assign directly to a variable:

```js
var char = ['chris:2255655', 'sarrah:5456454', 'taur:5655226']

var names = char.map(item => {

  var [name] = item.split(':'); // <- select only first index
  // var [name, id] = item.split(':'); // <- select first and second index
  // var [name, ...rest] = item.split(':'); // <- select first and rest of the elements
  // var [name,] = item.split(':'); // <- select first and skip next element index using ","

  return name;

})

console.log(names);
```